# Divide a number N into two parts in such a way that three times the square of one part plus twice the square of the other part shall be a minimum.

Tags: calculus

I'm reading a book (Calculus Made Easy - Silvanus Thompson) that has the following exercise:

> Divide a number N into two parts in such a way that three times
> the square of one part plus twice the square of the other part shall be
> a minimum.

It's part of a chapter that explains how to find minima/maxima using second-order derivatives. I'm quite confused on how to solve this problem.

I tried calculating the derivative of the following:

$$y = 3(xN)^2 + 2[(1-x)N]^2$$

Where $x$ represents a certain percentage of $N$. This gave me:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2N(5x-2)$$

Which I then equated to $0$, which gave me the wrong value for $x$ when comparing to the answer key (which is $0.4N, 0.6N$). Clearly I'm doing it wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please bear in mind that I'm trying to learn this stuff by myself without any proper math background.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $3(xN)^2$ instead?

Comment: $n$ and $N$ are different.  You shouldn't switch from one to the other.  The problem calls for squaring the first, not cubing, before multiplying by $3$

Comment: Note that if both parts are *squared* (instead of cubing one part and squaring the other), then a common factor of $N^2$ can be removed (distributed out) of the expression to be minimized.

Comment: @player3236 You're right! I changed it.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, now it all adds up, I get x = 4/10, which is the answer I'm looking for. Sometimes I get tunnel vision, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3x^2+2{(N-x)}^2=5x^2-4Nx+2N^2=5(x-\frac{2N}{5})^2+\frac{6N^2}{5}$

It will get min when $x=\frac{2N}{5}=0.4N$ and the other part is $0.6N$

Comment: Thanks very much for your clarification.

Answer (score 3):

After your edit, it looks correct.

$5x-2=0$ when $x=\frac25=0.4$, so $xN = 0.4 N$ and $(1-x)N=0.6N$.

Comment: Indeed, I came to the correct answer too. Thanks for your help.