# Completing the square: How does $5x^2−4Nx+2N^2$ get to this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, completing-the-square

I've been stuck on this for the past few hours. For context, you can refer to [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3837459/1210342), and in particular [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3837533) which makes sense, but skips over all the steps.

How does

$5x^2-4Nx+2N^2=$

Become

$5(x-\frac{2N}{5})^2+\frac{6N^2}{5}$?

Comment: make it a monic polynomial first.  Then complete the square with the first two terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let $P(x)$ be the polynomial you want,then we can factor out of the 5
$$P(x)=5\left(x^2-\frac45Nx+\frac25N^2\right)=5\left(x^2-2\cdot\frac25Nx+\frac25N^2\right)$$
Now since
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$
So
$$P(x)=5\left(\underbrace{x^2-2\cdot\frac25 Nx\color{red}{+\frac4{25}N^2}}_{\left(x-\frac{2N}{5}\right)^2}\color{red}{-\frac4{25}N^2}+\frac25N^2\right)=5\left(\left(x-\frac{2N}5\right)^2+\frac6{25}N^2\right)\\\boxed{P(x)=5\left(x-\frac{2N}{5}\right)^2+\frac65N^2}$$

Comment: Why does the -4/5Nx become -2 2/5Nx?

Comment: @Rene It appears that banana means $-\frac{4}{5} = -2 \cdot \frac{2}{5}$ rather than the mixed number $2~\frac{2}{5} = 2 + \frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

$$5x^2-4Nx+2N^2 = 5(x^2-\frac{4N}{5}x) \;+ 2N^2$$
Now, you add the square of half the $\frac{4N}{5}x$ term, without the $x$. But you also subtract it to balance the equation on the outside (Remember the 5 on the outside of the parentheses)
$$5(x^2-\frac{4N}{5}x \;+(\frac{4N}{10})^2)\;+2N^2-5(\frac{4N}{10})^2$$
$$5(x-\frac{4N}{10})^2\;+2N^2-5(\frac{4N}{10})^2$$
Simplifying,
$$5(x-\frac{2N}{5})^2+\frac{6N^2}{5}$$

Comment: Sorry, it should be fixed now.